# Smooth height transition with dynamic components in vuejs

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transitions

I created a little script in vuejs. It's a dialog, where the view can dynamically be changed when an event occurs.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWpVvW

As you can see, I have a nice little 1s fade transition when the component changes.
But both my components don't have the same size. One is one line, the other is multi-line. Therefore the height of the dialog is not the same. You can see on my codepen that the height of the window is "jumping" from small to big when transitioning from one view to the other. I am trying to achieve a smooth transition.

My idea to do that was to use flexbox.
The dialog and the card have been configured as vertical flexboxes.
The card and the card__text have been configured with a 2s transition and a flex-grow of 1.

```
.dialog {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
  flex: 1 1 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.card__text {
  flex: 1 1 1;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

Unfortunately the dialog is still not resizing smoothly. I'm pretty sure that this can be fixed by CSS, but I can't find how.

Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your are trying to achieve by using `flex-grow` here. `flex-grow` is used to manipulate how much an element will grow to take up the available space of its parent container.

What you should be animating is the `height`. However, since we don't know what the height of the new content will be without using JavaScript, a nice work around is to use the `max-height` property and animate it to a large value upon entry, and back to zero on leaving. This creates the smooth resize effect that you want. I have modified your pen with this change.

Check it out here: https://codepen.io/aamirkhan-91/pen/KoQXOM

Answer (score 0):

For more smooth transition you can try apply `height` transition on parent container element. In this solution you get content `height` in `beforeEnter` hook and apply this in parent wrapper with css transition settigs set. Inside this wrapper there is another transition for content fading effect with opacity animated.

[example](https://codepen.io/razz21/pen/XWWQrqP)

The only problem i found with this solution is `height` init value is unknown what causes no transition at first content change.